# while loop I/O redirection

Tags: bash, shell, unix, while-loop

I'm learning bash scripting. I reading about while loop and i/o redirection.
An example code for printing contents of a file list_of_files.txt ( File contains o/p of ls *.sh) is given as below

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "File Pls"
read file
while read -n  list; do
        echo "`cat $list`"
done<list_of_files.txt
```

However, Instead of taking the file from user I wanted to give it in the code itself. So I changed the code like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "File Pls"
file=`ls *.sh`
while read -n  list; do
        echo "`cat $list`"
done<"$file"
```

when I ran the script, below is the o/p :

```
[root@teja7134 bin]# suph.sh
File Pls
/root/bin/suph.sh: line 6: arr.sh
case.sh
for.sh
ifelse.sh
simple.sh
suph.sh
while.sh: No such file or directory
```

Why it is not displaying the contents of the shell scripts in the directory? Can some explain what mistake I made here?

Comment: See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Note also that a newline-delimited string *cannot* be safely used to contain a list of filenames, as filenames are able to contain literal newlines.

Comment: anyhow, `<"$file"` is reading from **exactly one** file, composed of the complete output of `ls *.sh` (since you assigned that complete output to the variable `file`). No such file by that name exists, hence your error.

Comment: I'd also strongly suggest getting in the habit of running `cat "$file"` instead of `echo "$(cat "$file")"`. (Running code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here isn't a bad habit to be in either).

Comment: BTW, in a real-world scenario, I'd write this operation more like `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.sh' -exec cat {} +`. That invokes as few `cat` instances as necessary for an arbitrarily large number of `.sh` files; if you didn't need to do even that, then `cat *.sh` gets you to the right place in a way that works even with files with oddball names (`touch $'foo\nbar.sh'`) and avoids all the unnecessary incidental complexity.

Comment: Are you sure the first code works? I get an `invalid number` error, probably because of the `-n` option for `read`?